# Xjs generates xsd:date without any extra annotation

Tags: date, xsd, xjc

I have an xsd with xsd:dateTime and xsd:date fields.
I use an xjc gradle job to generate my mapping sources.

Both end up as just a protected XMLGregorianCalendar;

I see that a date only needs some extra annotation like @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")

How do I get xjc to add the required annotation?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is a bug because I used an older version of XJC, upgrading to the latest version fixed the problem.